# SSH Tunnel to Ngrok and Initiate RDP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ngrok

I am trying to access my Linux machine from anywhere in the world. I have tried originally port forwarding and then ssh'ing in; however, I believe my school's WiFi won't allow port forwarding (every time I ran it, it would tell me connection refused). I have setup an account with ngrok and I can remotely SSH in, but now I am wondering if it is possible to RDP. I tried connecting via the Microsoft Remote Desktop app on Mac, but it instantly crashes. I have also looked at trying to connect with localhost, but it's not working. So far, I have tried (with xxxx being the port):

```
ssh -L xxxx:localhost:xxxx 0.tcp.ngrok.io
```

and

```
ssh -L xxxx:localhost:xxxx <user>@0.tcp.ngrok.io
```

but my computer won't allow it and after about 2 or 3 times, it warns me of a possible DNS Spoofing. Is there anyway that I can run a remote desktop of my linux machine that I have ssh tunneled to (from my mac) on ngrok? Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

First you'll need to [sign up with ngrok](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started) if you haven't already and you'll be given an authtoken. You'll need to install this by running

```
./ngrok authtoken <insert your token here>
```

This will save your token to a file located `../username/.ngrok/ngrok.yml`

Then you'll need to ask ngrok to [create a TCP tunnel](https://ngrok.com/docs#tcp) from their servers to your local machine's Remote Desktop port which should be 3389 by default

```
ngrok tcp 3389
```

Give it 30 seconds or so then jump to `http://localhost:4040/status` to see what the tcp address ngrok has allocated you. It should look something like `tcp://1.tcp.ngrok.io:158764`

Now you should be able to remote into your machine using address `1.tcp.ngrok.io:158764`

Comment: If following the steps above does not allow your Remote Desktop Client to connect, make sure your Windows machine's Remote Desktop is enabled. That's the trap I fell into. :)